# java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: invalid authorization specification - not found

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, hsqldb

I am trying to run a basic java desktop application using hibernate with an hsqldb in a standalone mode 
when I running my app I got this error

```
    java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: invalid authorization specification - not found: SA
```

Any help please

NB: I use netbeans IDE

I try this example [hibernate annotation](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hibernate-3-annotations)

and this is my hibernate conf file:

```
  <hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
   jdbc:hsqldb:C:\Users\Desktop\testdb</property>
  <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `username` and `password` you will not get that error.